# passing a conversion specifier as an argument to printf()

Tags: c, formatting, printf

Is there a way in C to pass `printf()` an argument which we want to use as conversion specifier? A little example:

Imagine I call my program with `./foo [-x]`

If `-x` is not present I want it to print some value in decimal. But if `-x` is present I'd like it to print that value in hexadecimal.

Is there a way to pass `printf()` the string which we want to use as a convertion specifier as an argument , in this case `"x"` or `"%s"` ?

--

Note: it's not something like

```
char *format = "%s";
printf(format, "a string");
```

that I'm looking for.

Comment: If your goal is to have something equivalent to this hypothetical `printf("%.8l@\n", (xflag ? "X" : "d"), 3141592L);` where `@` is used here to indicate that the conversion specifier is specified as a separate argument, then the answer is 'no'.  You'd have to create the appropriate format string: `printf((xflag ? "%.8lX" : "%.8ld"), 3141592L);`, which your "it's not something like" comment indicates you don't want to do, but my comment here says "you will have to do, or use something of your own devising other than the `printf()` family of functions".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your reply. I was just curious if printf() has this capability ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the *printf() family of functions do provide ways to pass field widths as arguments, the actual conversion specifiers themselves must be provided in the format string. Therefore, if your program needs to choose between `printf("%#X", integer)` and `printf("%d", integer)`, you either have to programmatically generate your format string (in something fairly similar to the manner you're explicitly rejecting at the end of your question) or you need to have two different calls to `printf()` with conditional code to choose between them. On the other hand, it doesn't seem terribly onerous to me to programmatically generate a format string, so long as all the possible different output formats use the same number of arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was just curious if printf() has this capability ;)

Comment: If this answer has been useful to you, please consider accepting it. (See [What's all this "accepting" about?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) )